# Laravel: class App\Posts does not exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have got this error so many times in Laravel as using model classes that says this class does not exists which it does. one of them was when i ran  `App\Post::count()` with **tinker** and got this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Post' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

and one was when i tried to seed the DB with model. this is the model content:

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;   
class Dog extends Model
{   
    //   
}
```

and this is the Seeder:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
 use \App\Dog;   
class DogsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function run()
    {
        Dog::query()->create(['name'=>'jack']);
    }
}
```

with this error: **Class 'App\Dog' not found**.and this is for every model i create.
any solution? (Laravel -V: 5.4, PHP -V: 7.2, Apache webserver)

Comment: `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes but no effect

Comment: where the is physical location of your App\dog

Comment: Whats the path that the model file is in?

Comment: @abr  in /app directory by default

Comment: @TahaPaksu in the /app directory

Comment: and the filename?

Comment: @lagbox Post.php

Comment: Question, does your php file start with <?php   and ends with   ?> or is it just <?

Comment: @abr it just starts with <?php

Comment: See if you can create a dog by using: \App\Dog::create(['name' => 'jack']);  if you still can't do it, check your file permissions

Comment: What are you typing into Psy Shell?

Comment: @abr   changing namespace call didn't work, and even 755 chmod had no effect. rare issue :(

Comment: @abr App\Post::count()

Comment: Check the name of your file, it must be `Post.php`.

Comment: @ako yes it is.

Comment: Absolutely the problem is with your composer autoloader, try `composer dump-autoload`. And run `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: where did You wrote `use App\Dog;`  ?  above the `public function run` or above the `class` ?  can You add full text of seeder code?

Comment: @num8er      sure. i added.

Comment: @ako yes it seems, but i've tried them too, i'm afraid there's no way but creating a new project.

Comment: installing, creating new project is same as runing: `rm -rf vendor && composer install`

Comment: @num8er just the same

Comment: You are trying to load `\App\Dog` but your file name is `Post.php`... rename it to `Dog.php` or change to `\App\Post`. You can't have both.

Comment: @ChinLeung  no they are two different isuues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to fix the same issue about half hour on laravel 5.8 with php v7.2, I noticed, that my php file started with `<?` output delimiter. Changing `<?` to `<?php` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use this path.

```
>>> App\Models\Post
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is necessary to clear the cache, this command worked in my case:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I hope it works for you too

regards

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

On some servers you need to prefix App with \ like: 
namespace \App;

Also after the above change:

- Also double check class name in model
- run composer dump-autoload
- php artisan cache:clear

Comment: class not found has nothing to do with migration

Comment: true, removed unnecessary steps

Answer (score 0):

Use this path, hope you got your answer

> > > App\Models\Post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [@MoviesLiker already submitted this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283065/3025856) a couple of months ago, and with correct formatting. Please be sure to read existing answers before contributing a new one. Once you've done that, it's still fine to contribute a new answer if you have something new to add to the conversation. Otherwise, in the future, once you've earned more reputation, you'll be able to upvote existing answers as a way of validating that they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this path

```
App\Post
```

Use this path

```
App\Models\Post
```

Comment: It looks like there is missing more information in the answer; what do you mean by 'Use this path'?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with `App\Post::count()` but it works when I add Models before the Post. You can try that one too.

```
App\Models\Post::count()
```

So, in your case:

```
App\Models\Dog
```